# SQL query to join 4 Tables and get sum of 3 columns from 3 different tables and show result into asp.net mvc view

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a new asp.net mvc learner and I am trying to make a simple application for fish firming like where fish businessman could store their data ...so I have 3 tables and are
1.fish_set
2.fish_food
3.additional cost

and in those tables has column like fish_price,food_price,additional_cost,in above 3 tables. I have another table that's named 'Total cost' and column name like total_fish cost, total food cost, total additional cost and i want to get that kind of data from above 3 tables into 'total cost table',,one thing more each table has a column 'pondid'

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried with Linq query but that's not working and as i said i am new so please help me if you can

Comment: "I have tried with Linq query".  Where???  I don't see a code posted.